# Where to ask question about meaning/usage of a word in English that comes from Greek and is about programming?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have been dabbling in meaning of words and I was wondering which community to ask about the possible usage of the word *"meme"* in English which started in Greek *"mimeme"*. Google gives me the definition of *"an element of a culture or system of behaviour passed from one individual to another by imitation or other non-genetic means"* and somewhere else I get *"something imitated"*.

I would like to use the word in the context of programming because of our nature of imitating older languages when we create new ones.

My current elaboration of the word is: *"That which is imitated from language to language. e.g.: loops and control statements"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com). Word etymology is on topic, so the issue of crossing into Greek origins is not a concern. And if the "programming context" is important, simply specify that in the post itself. That type of "domain knowledge needed" is always apt.

Comment: Oh, so that's fine to do too. Did not know that. Thanks!